# Android ImageViews in GridLayout rendering problem

Tags: android, imageview, android-gridlayout

I have a strange problem with GridLayout containing ImageViews.

**This is my layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:src="@drawable/test" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:src="@drawable/test" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:src="@drawable/test" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:src="@drawable/test" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:src="@drawable/test" />

</GridLayout>
```

**This is what I would like to achieve:**

[image: Desired layout]

**However, the layout doesn't seem to scale at all and looks like this (depending on the size of screen):**

[image: Actual layout]

**What I have tried (and did not work):**

- Adding `android:clipChildren="false"` in GridLayout
- Setting `scaleType` of ImageViews as `fitXY`, `fitCenter` and `centerCrop`
- Setting `layout_width` and `layout_height` of ImageViews to `wrap_content`, `match_parent` and their permutations (however, I would expect the GridLayout to set size of its children automatically)

Could someone more experienced please tell me how to achieve my goal? :D  Thank you!

PS: If there is any other layout which I could use to achieve the desired look, please let me know.

Comment: If your number of images are going to be dynamic, then you should use recycler-view

Comment: And if images are static, then you can just use viewgroups such as linear layout or constraint layout

Comment: @Parag Pawar It will be just a static layout. I have tried nested LinearLayouts, but it doesn't look nice - sometimes the images are a bit off. I will give a try to ContraintLayout, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify `layout_width` / `layout_height` and also `layout_columnWeight` / `layout_rowWeight` for the child views. It is similar to weights in LinearLayout.

Use it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:src="@drawable/test" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:src="@drawable/test" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:src="@drawable/test" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:src="@drawable/test" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:src="@drawable/test" />

</GridLayout>
```

Btw I recommend you to use GridLayout from JetPack (AndroidX) as it has fixed some bugs and has better implementation overall for different Android versions - https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/gridlayout

When using this AndroidX version, you would just replace android:* namespace of layout_rowWeight / columnWeight / layout_row / layout_column to app:* namespace.

Comment: Thank you, my friend! :D  Btw: Is there any explanation why we need to set layout_width and layout_height to 0dp?

Comment: @Firzen I'm not sure. Probably to allow specify width/height for some views explicitly (as it will have higher priority) and for other views use weights. So instead of adding new attribute they just reused already required layout_width/layout_height. It's similar/same as using weights in LinearLayout.